# Arithmetic operators in JADE

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using Jade template engine with NOde.js.
I have two variables:

```
a = 0.0378
b = 0.1545
```

in Jade I do:

```
- var result = a + b*2
```

and I get a very strange number when I do `#{result}`

**0.03780.309**

It seems to concatenate the numbers as strings.
Could someone tell me how can I use arithmetic operators in Jade?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that `a` (and also `b`) is a number and not a string?

If it is a string you will need to to convert it to a number via `parseFloat`:

```
- var result = parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b)*2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    h2 Jade的 operation
    - var a = 8
    - var b = 2
    p #{+a+b}
    p #{+a-b}
    p #{+a*b}
    p #{+a/b}
```