# How to do javascript math in a jade template?

Tags: javascript, pug

I want the lightness to be a function of order of item on the list

Here's the order variable

```
{{order}}
```

Here's the template language I'm trying to modify

```
.minicard(style="background-color:hsl(354,100%,{{(order * 2)+46}}%)")
```

What I'm basically trying to do is multiply order by 2 and add 46 to it.

{{order}} works but doing math within the curly brackets doesn't seem to. How do I do simple javascript in a jade template?

Comment: have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940860/javascript-function-execution-inside-jade-template?

Comment: jade is server side, javascript is client side.  besides that, `{{ }}` is usually some client side framework notation, maybe AngularJs or Handlebars?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368040/arithmetic-operators-in-jade

Comment: It's using Meteor

Comment: I think it should be `#{yourValue}`.As it is jade Interpolation are written like this.Nothing to do with metor

Answer (score 0):

No need for JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
- order = 10
- order = order * 2 + 45

.minicard(style="background-color:hsl(354,100%,"+order+"%;")
```

OR you can do it inline:

```
- order = 10

.minicard(style="background-color:hsl(354,100%," + (order * 2 + 45) + "%;")
```

Both should compile into:

```
<div class="minicard" style="background-color:hsl(354,100%,65%"></div>
```

See working example here - https://codepen.io/AdamCCFC/pen/pWoxXV

Comment: I don't think math works for meteor jade (mquandalle/jade)